# Windows appear in odd places in Yosemite

Tags: macos, window-manager

Since upgrading to Yosemite when it came out, windows in different apps randomly appear in odd places - eg, not connected to their parents window. Here's the Chrome search bar:

[image: Windows appear in odd places in Yosemite]

Sometimes it's worse, sometimes it's better, but it's never 100% OK. This happens in multiple apps. **Restarting the OS or the app does not help**. How can I made windows appear in normal places again on Yosemite?

Comment: First thing I'd do is go to System Preferences > Displays and switch out of the resolution selected to another resolution, quit System Preferences,  relaunch, then set the resolution back to the original. If the resolution setting is 'Default for display', click the Scaled radio button and set a resolution. My thinking is that some .plist is corrupted or something, and deliberately making changes would write over the .plist correctly. Report back with your findings,

Comment: What kind of mac are you working with? If not an iMac, what sort of external monitor and connection (VGA, HDMI, DVI, etc) are you using?

Comment: @IconDaemon MBA 2013, DisplayPort connecting to a ViewSonic 2560x1440 monitor.

Comment: Where does this strangeness occur, on the VeiwSonic? Is the MBA lid up or down? Are you mirroring or 2 separate displays?

Comment: @IconDaemon On the ViewSonic, MBA lid is down, single display. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth trying to login as another user, either creating a new user, or using the guest account to see if it happens there also, if it does not. It would suggest the issue is with the preferences in your user account, especially if it only happens in some apps, you can look to clear their caches and preferences. However if it continues, I would suggest backup and reinstall the operating system.